# php,postgresql,mysql

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I am stuck in a query.i don't know wats the problem exactly..can any 1 help me??

Here is the code:

while i run the query it throws the error: ERROR:  relation "CONTRACTORS" does not exist
LINE 5:       from "CONTRACTORS"

```
select  cont.name, cont.total,cp.contractor_id,cp.amount_paid,wt.id
                FROM
                (
                  select name,sum(amount_to_be_paid) as total
                  from "CONTRACTORS"
                  group by name
                ) cont
                left join
                (
                  select contractor_id,sum(amount_paid) as amount_paid
                  from "CONTRACTOR_PAYMENTS" 
                  group by contractor_id
                ) cp

                    on cont.id= cp.contractor_id
                              left join worktypeids as wt on cont.worktypeid_id = wt.id AND wt.project_id=2
```

Comment: Never dealt with PostgreSQL but if this were MySQL I wouldn't be quoting the table name.

Comment: quoting the table name makes the table name case sensitive; if the query shown below made it work, your problem was that you have a contractors table and not a CONTRACTORS table. so, yes, writing it without quotes would have made it work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select  cont.name, cont.total,cp.contractor_id,cp.amount_paid,wt.id
                FROM
                (
                  select  name,id, sum(amount_to_be_paid) as total
                  from contractors group by name,id
                ) cont
                left join
                (
                  select contractor_id,sum(amount_paid) as amount_paid
                  from contractor_payments
                  group by contractor_id
                ) cp

                  on cont.id = cp.contractor_id
                              left join worktypeids as wt on cont.worktypeid_id = wt.id AND wt.project_id=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add table structure also ?

In first alias named as `cont`, which is join with `cp`, so for cont, you need select `id` column as well.

Better post table structure and and what you want in output ?