# php,mysql,postgresql

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, group-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php,postgresql,mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027801/php-postgresql-mysql)

i want to filter query to produce a result like:

`sum of amount_to_be_paid`, `contractor name` , `sum of amount paid` .

here my problem is in table mapping. It produces double results bcoz contractor_task's table has 2 entries with same contractor but different worktypeids. plz tell me how to get a single result of contractor even he worked on different tasks.

Query:

```sql
select distinct contractors.name, cont.total,cp.amount_paid
                FROM
                (
                  select contractor_id,sum(amount_to_be_paid) as total
                  from contractor_tasks left join worktypeids as wt on worktypeid_id = wt.id where wt.project_id=2
                  group by contractor_id
                )cont
                left join
                (
                  select project_id,contractor_id,sum(amount_paid) as amount_paid
                  from contractor_payments 
                  group by contractor_id,project_id
                )cp

                    on cont.contractor_id= cp.contractor_id
                              left join contractors on cont.contractor_id=contractors.id
```

Comment: adding sample records with desired result would help the problem more easier to understand than analyzing the query you have created `:D`

Comment: it will do grouping fine if i remove the id field form subquery of contractors..but if i remove that then it gives error.there is some issue in my sub query..

Comment: **DO NOT** repost questions.